# Can I remove a spawnpoint?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I set a spawnpoint using commands for me or another player, I keep spawning at that exact point, with an exception: when I change it. What I want, though, is to remove it completely and spawn at the world spawn instead.

I've even done research on such a trivial command, but didn't find anything about it's removal.

Is it possible to remove an individual spawn point using commands? If not are there other ways to do it (like modifying the file it is in)?

Comment: Yep. And it's mentioned somewhere in my 370 answers on this site. :D I'll search for it.

Comment: Found it! https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346974